# Java Eclipse debugging shortcuts in "Editing Java Source"

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

I like to use shortcuts while debugging my java applications in eclipse. The keys F5,F6,F7 and F8 only work in debugging perspective. So I tried to copy all keys (Preference -> General -> Keys) with the "Copy Command" button and make them work when "Editing Java Source". I hit "Apply" button, but still doesn't work.

**How do I make the keys (F5,F6,F7 and F8) work in java perspective?** Thank you!

Best regards,

Kon

Edit: I use Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1

Comment: At some debug points I don't need the entire debug information like the call tree, variables, expressions etc. - so I just stay in java perspective to have more space on my screen for the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this old [bug 13513](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13513):

> To get the "<kbd>F</kbd>" buttons to work, you currently have to enable the debug action 
>   set.

```
Window->Customize Perspective->Action Sets->Debug.
```

So you shouldn't need to copy key preferences around, just to activate Debug commands in your current perspective.